# Is it possible to apply water ripples to GIF using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using [WaterRipples.java](https://github.com/danielweck/android-libgdx-playground/blob/master/LibGDX_Playground/src/daniel/weck/WaterRipples.java) to add ripple effects to simple .png/.jpg files. Now I want to add ripples to a .gif file. but I am unable to do so.

My code for rendering GIF:

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
           batch.begin();
           Object[] objects = mAnimation.getKeyFrames();
           Array<TextureRegion> textureRegionArray = (Array<TextureRegion>) objects[0];
           if (gifFrameRenderCounter == textureRegionArray.size) {
               gifFrameRenderCounter = 0;
           }
           Log.d("GDX_LIB", "ripple draw frame with ripple... " + gifFrameRenderCounter);
           batch.draw(textureRegionArray.get(gifFrameRenderCounter), 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
           batch.end();
```

I am generatin the animation object using [GifDecoder](https://github.com/pltxtra/kngtz/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/holidaystudios/kngt/tools/GifDecoder.java).

How do i render water ripple effects on GIF since waterripple.java is modifying vertices to achieve ripples.